# Why do we use file extensions if the content is just plain text?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, file-extension

From what I can see, a browser will display the information found both in .txt files or .html files, properly displaying html tags inside them. My g++ compiler won't stop segnaling errors in a .lua file containing lua code, but it will still try compiling it without caring about the extension, while the lua interpreter won't even open a .cpp file, even if I wrote a perfectly working lua program inside.

So why do we need file extensions if the content is in all cases text? As I said, I could write a C++ program in a file with an arbitrary extension and it will properly compile it, so what are extensions even for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On many systems you can associate extensions with certain applications. For example a double click on a .cpp file will open it in a C++ IDE while a double click on a .txt file will open it in the default text editor.

Another example: Most text editors have syntax highlighting that depends on the extension.

There are probably many more cases where the extension is useful as an indicator for the file type. Of course this is nothing but a convention, but one that has been established for decades.